# Is there any way to create a listener in c# which takes the 10 messages from Amazon SQS queue and store in the database at my end?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

For now I have written the below lines of code and by these I am getting only the first message present in the queue

```
 string message = string.Empty;
        ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest();           
        receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = "The URL of my queue";
        receiveMessageRequest.MaxNumberOfMessages = 10;
        ContactsDTO DTOobj = new ContactsDTO();
        ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse = objClient.ReceiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);

        List<Message> messagesList = new List<Message>();
        messagesList = receiveMessageResponse.Messages;

        foreach (Message objMessage in messagesList)
        {
            message += objMessage.Body;
            receiptHandle = objMessage.ReceiptHandle;
        }
        Session["MessageReceiptHandle"] = receiptHandle;
        var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ContactsDTO obj = s.Deserialize<ContactsDTO>(message);
```

My ContactsDTO class is :-

```
 public class ContactsDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html search for text "MaxNumberOfMessages" in the page and read the description of it.

Comment: I have gone through this link and applied the "MaxNumberOfMessages" attribute but still I am receiving a single message@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: That's what the article explains. There is no guarantee that you will receive 10 messages. You may receive less than 10 but never more than 10. That's a known issue and there is no solution for this. You can try putting a loop keep receiving messages and check count and exit the loop when message count is zero.

Comment: Okay..!! Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I will try putting a loop to receive messages. @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0):

Aws has distributed servers and messages are also distributed across different servers. That's why you are not getting all the messages in single call, as partially messages are being stored on different servers.

What you can do here is, put a while 1 loop that continuously fetches the message from queue and store it in DB.

And run that script as a nohup process, so that it won't stop running. So whenever producers send any message on queue, it gets directly fetched by nohup consumer.

Comment: How can we continuously fetch the message from queue and store it in DB?

Comment: While 1 loop is an infinite loop, just run your script that is used to fetch messages from queue in while(true) loop. And on server run it as a nohup process. So that it won't stop untill you manually kill that process.